# Dynamodb new item notification/trigger

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a function in  Amazon Java SDK that notifies when a new item is added to a table?

I believe it should be a synchronous function that hold program execution, until there is a new item.

Latency should be low, like less than a second.

Comment: It seems like you're using the wrong tool. You probably want to base your system around messages sent through SQS. If you still need DynamoDB for storage, why not include a reference to the item in the SQS message?

Comment: @DarkFalcon My impression is that for few (under 100) messages, SQS latencies could be high, like 5 seconds. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: They never have been in my testing, but I presume they could be. On the other hand, SQS provides a way to actually accomplish this while DynamoDB doesn't (unless you want to use polling).

Comment: @DarkFalcon What are you usual latencies from your tests?

Comment: That is difficult to measure as it was going over the Internet, not to an EC2 instance, but definitely not much more than the round trip time. From visual observation of my app, it seemed instantaneous.

Comment: @DarkFalcon This notification of a new message, it should be implemented by long polling?

Comment: That would be my recommendation, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Lambda and DynamoDB Streams and attach a lambda function to the stream to process item updates in your table.